# Logback is not generating log files on Ubuntu

Tags: java, logging, ubuntu, logback

We have configured logback for our logging needs in our application. When we run our application on Windows machine, it works as expected and generates the log files with proper logs. However when we deployed the same runnable jar file on Ubuntu machine, it is not generating log files. Following is the code in logback.xml

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <!-- in the absence of the class attribute, it is assumed that the
         desired discriminator type is
         ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator -->
<discriminator>
  <key>uniqueNumber</key>
  <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
</discriminator>
<sift>
  <appender name="FILE-${uniqueNumber}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${uniqueNumber}.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                    <FileNamePattern>${uniqueNumber}_%i.log</FileNamePattern>
                    <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
                    <MaxIndex>10000</MaxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                    <MaxFileSize>5MB</MaxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>
</sift>
  </appender>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anything goes wrong with the configuration [logback prints out a lot of debug messages to System.out](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting). If you do not see those, then perhaps the files ARE generated but you just don't know where.

You can explicitly enable logback printing with `<configuration debug="true">` which should give you much more to work on.

If you just cannot locate the files consider using `lsof` to locate the full path of the open files of your application.

Comment: Hi @Thorbjorn, Thanks for your answer. I searched for the files in the same folder as the running jar, also searched the log files in root folder, var/logs folder and in some more folders without luck.Also I did not get any debug messages.

Comment: Did you enable logback debug diagnostics?

Comment: Yes I enabled debug diagnostics and can see the logs on Windows like logback-test.xml not found, found logback.xml..etc..

Comment: Try `lsof`.  May require root permission.

Comment: hi @Thorbjorn, I had kept the logback.xml in the jar file itself, which was causing problem. Alongwith that write permissions were not set to the folder. Hence, log file was not generating. Printing out the debug messages helped me a lot. Thanks for that.

Comment: Why did that cause problems?  logback can find logback.xml in the classpath (I actually use an `include` in my logback.xml to have configuration in the file system)

Comment: I Would suggest raising a bug with logback.  It should be reported very loudly that logs cannot be written.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours, even with a simpler logback configuration.

In my `logback.xml` file I used absolute paths instead of relative ones for the appender, but my configuration is Linux-only, and the machines where we deploy our Java application all share the same configuration/partitioning-scheme.

The files, at least this is what was happening to me, should be one directory up of your application directory. Lets say you are executing your JAR from `PATH/my.jar`, the logs should be in `../PATH`.

Comment: Hello Milo, Thanks for sharing your experience. I searched the files almost everywhere on the system, but could not locate.